# Spatial form of an atom and type of chemical bond

Tags: quantum-chemistry, molecular-orbital-theory, molecular-structure

As we know, the first excited states of Hydrogen atoms is $2p$.
The wave functions in cartesian basis we can represent as
$$
p_x          = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \left( Y_{1, +1} + Y_{1, -1}\right)  =\sqrt{\frac{3}{16\pi}} \frac{x}{r}          \\
p_y          = \frac{i}{\sqrt{2}} \left( Y_{1, +1} - Y_{1, -1}\right)  = \sqrt{\frac{3}{16\pi}} \frac{y}{r}          \\
p_z          = Y_{1,0}                                                 = \sqrt{\frac{3}{4\pi}} \frac{z}{r}        
$$
which is visulize in forms of dumbells:

[image]

My question as follows:

1. **An H-atom in an excited state has the same shape?**
2. **How does an atom determines the axis along which to orient?** Assuming that the directions equiprobable, the shape should be spherical. **Or I'm wrong?**
3. Type of chemical bond ($\sigma$, $\pi$, ...) is determined by the form of the type of atomic orbital ($s$, $p$, $d$, ..., or by their hybrides), but **how it is possible if an atom is spherical yet?**
   [image]

Comment: (1) The first excited state could also be considered to be that with the electron in the 2s orbital. (2) In the absence of an external field (electric/magnetic) there is no preferred orientation of an atom. The Stark and Zeeman effects show the effect of external fields. (3) You are effectively asking someone to explain all about chemical bonding which is far too big a subject for here, but is explained in numerous texts as is the theory of the H atom.